# Commutator in unitary transformation

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm reading a book on groups and representations in physics and I'm struggling to understand one of the equations as it introduces tensor operators, and I been able to find anything online to help with it.The context is:

$X_1, X_2, X_3$ are the generators for rotations of SO(3).

A spherical tensor operator $T^j_m$ is defined as an operator with the property that it transforms under rotations as $$U(R)T^j_mU(R)^{-1} = \sum_{m'}D^j_{mm'}(R)T^j_{m'}$$
where $U(R)$ is the unitary operator induced in the space of quantum states by a rotation $R$, and $D^j_{mm'}$ are the components of a j-dimensional representation of the group.

The book then gives an example, which is to consider $R = R_3(\theta)$, i.e. the rotation generated by $X_3$, and consider the transformation of $X_+ = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}(X_1+iX_2)$. It is the first line that confused me:
$$e^{-iX_3\theta}X_+e^{iX_3\theta} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}(X_1\cos(\theta)+X_2\sin(\theta)+i(X_2\cos(\theta)-X_1\sin(\theta)) = X_+e^{-i\theta}$$

It simply states that it achieves this using the commutation relations, which I am aware of, but I don't really understand how one does this using the exponentiation of the operator $X_3$. If someone could explain in detail that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know specifically what the author had in mind, but typically the idea is to use commutations to "push" the two exponentials next to each other, that is, try and compute $[X_{+} , e^{iX_{3} \theta}]$, then use the result to replace $ X_{+} e^{iX_{3} \theta} $ with $[X_{+} , e^{iX_{3} \theta}] +e^{iX_{3} \theta}X_{+}$

Comment: The commutation relations the author mentions that are used in this are just those that define the Lie algebra of SO(3):
$[X_3, X_1] = iX_2$, $[X_3,X_2] = -iX_2$

Comment: OK, so what is $[X_{+} , e^{iX_{3} \theta}]$? You can expand the exponential or some other trick

Comment: Yes, I have tried to calculate this already, I am aware that this is what I should be doing, but I am quite stuck, I simply get a sum over k of terms with $[X_1,X_3^k]$ and similarly for $X_2$, but I do not see how to simplify this, for example, by using the commutation relation $[A, BC...YZ] = BC...Y[A,Z] + BC...[A,Y]Z+...$

Comment: try assuming $\theta$ is very small, and then consider the result as a differential equation.

Comment: How can it be a differential equation

Answer (score 2):

A more straightforward way to see this is to use the result that for any matrices $U,V$
$$
e^{\theta U}V e^{-\theta U} = e^{\theta \operatorname{ad}_U}V,
$$
where $\operatorname{ad}_U$ is the operator that sends $V$ to $[U, V]$. To see why this result is true, note that both sides satisfy the differential equation $\frac{d}{d\theta}S(\theta) = \operatorname{ad}_U(S(\theta))$, and agree when $\theta = 0$.  By the [Picard-Lindelöf Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) solutions of this ODE with the same initial condition are unique, so both sides must agree.

Using this result, you can write
$$
e^{-iX_3\theta}X_+e^{iX_3\theta} = e^{\theta\operatorname{ad}_{-iX_3}}X_+ = e^{-i\theta\operatorname{ad}_{X_3}}X_+.
$$
Then since $\operatorname{ad}_{X_3}X_+ = X_+$, the result follows.